# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location') When Adding Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

The react app was working until I added React Router it showes this error

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')*

> React App

```
import { Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
 return (
   <Router>
     <div className="App">
       <Header />
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/" component={MainPage}></Route>
       </Switch>
     </div>
   </Router>
 );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

react-router-dom doesn't export Router instead it exports BrowserRouter
so the code should be one of the following

> First

```
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

```
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={MainPage}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

> Second

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

```
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={MainPage}></Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
```